# Google Charts Display Issue

Tags: charts, google-visualization, appian

I'm facing an issue that the column name is not showing in the placeholders outside the graph. The image is attached. I'm using appian tool. I have column data in chartColData variable & rowData in chartRowData. All the data seems to be correct, but if you think I'm missing column labels from here, kindly point out.
[image: No Name is showing of any data]

```
local!chartColData: {
    {
      type: "string",
      id: "Month",
      rowDataKey: "Month"
    },
    {
      type: "number",
      id: "Bolivia",
      rowDataKey: "Bolivia"
    },
    {
      type: "number",
      id: "Ecuador",
      rowDataKey: "Ecuador"
    },
    {
      type: "number",
      id: "Balanced",
      rowDataKey: "Balanced"
    }
  },
  local!chartRowData:{
    {
      Month: "2018",
      Bolivia: 165,
      Ecuador: 938,
      Balanced: 650
    },
    {
      Month: "2019",
      Bolivia: 768,
      Ecuador: 1120,
      Balanced: 546
    },
    {
      Month: "2020",
      Bolivia: 897,
      Ecuador: 1167,
      Balanced: 793
    },
    {
      Month: "2021",
      Bolivia: 1392,
      Ecuador: 1110,
      Balanced: 638.5
    },
    {
      Month: "2022",
      Bolivia: 136,
      Ecuador: 969,
      Balanced: 739
    }
  }
```

Comment: are you able to share the code? it appears the data table column labels for those two series are missing.

Comment: where is the data table for the chart created? otherwise, maybe try adding a `label` property to each `chartColData`